# Decorate two functions?

Tags: python, python-unittest, web-api-testing

Is it possible to make such test cases shorter by using decorator or whatever else?

```
    def test_login_invalid_pwd(self):
        password = '12345'
        response = self._login(pwd=password)
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response['resultText'],
                         'invalid password or login')
        self.assertEqual(response['resultCode'], 55)

    def test_web_login_invalid_login(self):
        login = 'my_1258@'
        response = self._login(login=login)
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response['resultText'],
                         'invalid password or login')
        self.assertEqual(response['resultCode'], 55)
```

Comment: you can always start by grouping the asserts in a single function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Try this:

```
def helper(self, response):
    self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(response['resultText'],
                     'invalid password or login')
    self.assertEqual(response['resultCode'], 55)

def test_login_invalid_pwd(self):
    password = '12345'
    response = self._login(pwd=password)
    self.helper(response)

def test_web_login_invalid_login(self):
    login = 'my_1258@'
    response = self._login(login=login)
    self.helper(response)
```

Or, depending on how granular your tests need to be, and assuming that your `._login()` method uses `None` as defaults:

```
def test_login_invalid(self):
    for login, pwd in (('my_1258@', None), (None, '12345')):
        response = self._login(login=login, pwd=pwd)
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response['resultText'],
                         'invalid password or login')
        self.assertEqual(response['resultCode'], 55)
```